# How to implement multi-images on screen, each can be selected, moved, rotated, zoomed and bordered?

Tags: android, image, imageview, border, selection

User can select some images to the screen, and be able to select/drag/move/zoom/rotate each image. When an image is selected, it will have a blue border. And user can also bring an image to the front or background.

Here is sample picture in the following: there are two images(girls) on a star-background. The top one has been selected(it has a blue border).

[image]

I don't know have to implement it. For several days of learning, I can now drag/move/zoom/rotate a single image(inside an imageview, and scaled by matrix). But I don't know how to handle multi-images.

I want to know:

1. Is it still a good idea to use ImageView(for each image), or what classes should I use?
2. How to implement the orders? (so I can bring them to front or background)
3. How to determine which image has been selected
4. How to find and draw the border of selected image?

For now, I just know how to use ImageView, but I'm not sure if I can use it to implement this task. Please give me some advices, thanks !

Comment: hi i have same problem did u help me in that problem kind of u.......give example to me please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing everything directly onto a Canvas is one way of doing it. There is an article that covers the basics of using a Canvas. You can read it [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

There is one major downside in doing this - you have to handle all the input events by yourself. The API won't tell you which image has been clicked, or dragged. You'll have to implement that by yourself.

Comment: Can I extend a `View` and implement my logic in `onDraw`, and handle touch in `onTouch`? To determine which image has been selected, I have to check which image under the pressing-point?

Comment: Yes. Remember to avoid any heavy computation or database access and so on in those methods. Especially in onDraw.